# image sequence animation load only once not infinitely

Tags: javascript, html, css

below is my code,In this 1 to 15 image and this image load one by one to 15 and again start from 1 to 15 in specific time interval.  In this sequence images play infinitely when page is load but i want images play at only once when page is load.
and I can't fixed this bug please help me out to solve this problem.

```js
onload = function startAnimation() { 
  var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
  var frameCount = frames.length;
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function () { 
      frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
      frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
  }, 100); 
}
```

```css
#animation img {
    display: none;
}
#animation img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation"> 
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging02.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging03.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging04.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging05.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging06.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging07.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging08.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging09.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging10.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging11.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging12.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging13.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging14.png">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging15.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pratik, this should help you:
You should use `clearInterval` like below:

```
if(j === 15) {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Example

```js
onload = function startAnimation() {
            var animDiv = document.getElementById('animation');
            var x = document.createElement("IMG");
            x.setAttribute("id", 'test');
            x.setAttribute("src",
                "http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png");
            animDiv.appendChild(x);

            var i = 1,
                j = 2;
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                var y = (i < 10) ? '0' + i.toString() : i.toString(),
                    z = (j < 10) ? '0' + j.toString() : j.toString(),
                    url = document.getElementById('test').src;
                document.getElementById('test').src = url.replace(y, z);
                i++;
                j++;
                if (j === 16) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
```

```css
#animation img {
  display: none;
}

#animation img:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">

</div>
```

Comment: your code is almost correct but your image sequence end with first image but i want sequence is end with last image(image number 15)

Comment: @pratik yes, it should be `j === 14` in `if` condition. My bad :)

Comment: yes this is absolutely correct but can you create on loop on <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01, 02, 03...., 015.png" ?is this possible?

Comment: @pratik you can use it like below:

    var animDiv = document.getElementById('animation');
            for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
                var x = document.createElement("IMG"),
                    y = (i < 10) ? '0' + i.toString() : i.toString();
                x.setAttribute("src",
                    "http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging" + y + ".png");
                animDiv.appendChild(x);
            }

Comment: i tried this code but didn't get the output.so please attach your code in your snippet.

Comment: this is also right but i want once image tag define than image number (1,2,3...15)will change automatically  in this path only ,not every time new tags will be generate 
i.e
http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging1,2,3...15.png

Comment: @pratik Can you please recheck and update me whether you want like this ?

Comment: in your first script image is flickering in my code and this script is not working in firefox. is this any problem?

onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("animation-banner").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
        frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        j++;
        if(j === 49) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }); }

Answer (score 1):

You should use `clearInterval();`

```js
onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;
    var i = 0;
    var myInterval=setInterval(function () { 
       if(i==frameCount-2){
         clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
        frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        
    }, 100); 
}
```

```css
#animation img {
    display: none;
}
#animation img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation"> 
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging02.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging03.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging04.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging05.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging06.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging07.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging08.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging09.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging10.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging11.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging12.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging13.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging14.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging15.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: yes you code almost correct but  i want after all image load last image is 15th number of image not 1st number.

Comment: i dont understand you.Can u give more explain? @pratik.

Comment: simply i want image sequence end with last image

Comment: yes this is absolutely correct but can you create on counter on <img src="jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01, 02, 03...., 015.png" ?is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your interval once you want it to stop running. Using `clearInterval()`.

Check this example:

Note that `intervalEnd` is the number that once the `i` reaches it, will clear your interval.

```js
onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;
    var i = 0;
    var intervalEnd = 100;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () { 
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
        frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        if (i >= intervalEnd)
          clearInterval(intervalId)
    }, 100); 
}
```

```css
#animation img {
    display: none;
}
#animation img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation"> 
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging02.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging03.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging04.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging05.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging06.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging07.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging08.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging09.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging10.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging11.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging12.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging13.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging14.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging15.png" />
</div>
```